# How to disable horizontal scrolling of UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIView` like iPhone's Springboard. I have created it using a `UIScrollView` and `UIButtons`. I want to disable horizontal scrolling on said scrollview. I want only vertical scrolling. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You should change your title : you ask for horizontal in the question and vertical in the title. People find your questions later on search engines, so it still matters 2 years later :)

Comment: @RahulVyas The man above has a point. Changing the title will decrease any confusion for beginners who get here through a search engine (such as me ;) ).

Comment: Have edited the title on the poster's behalf. (Though it is currently awaiting peer review before the edit will be visible.)

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You have to set the `contentSize` property of the `UIScrollView`.  For example, if your `UIScrollView` is 320 pixels wide (the width of the screen), then you could do this:

```
CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(320, myScrollableHeight);
[myScrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];
```

The `UIScrollView` will then only scroll vertically, because it can already display everything horizontally.

Comment: Hi. This solution works really fine! Thanks for that. I tried setting the static width to 0. For me this works too. I don't know if there might be some side effects later. But if one doesn't know the size (i.e. universal code for iPhone and iPad) this works great!

Comment: I think better to do CGSizeMake(0, myScrollableHeight), so horizontal scrolling disabled even if not all subviews showed.

Comment: NB Setting one of the dimensions to 0 when using paging will cause VoiceOver to announce the page number as "page 1 of 1" regardless of the correct value

Comment: Instead of passing width as 320 hardcoded, we can pass like:

CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollview.frame.size.width, myScrollableHeight);
[myScrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];

Answer (score 99):

**UPDATED:** (After @EranMarom pointed out on his comment)

You can **stop horizontal scrolling or vertical scrolling** in the `ScrollViewDelegate` Method.
Here it is how,

**Stops Horizontal Scrolling:**

If you want to scroll horizontally, then you need to increase the contentOffset.x. Preventing that stops the scrollview scroll in horizontal direction.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    sender.contentOffset.x = 0.0
}
```

**Stops Vertical Scrolling:**

If you want to scroll vertically, then you need to increase the contentOffset.y. Preventing that stops the scrollview scroll in vertical direction.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    sender.contentOffset.y = 0.0
}
```

Above code prevents the changes in `x` and `y` of a `scrollview contentOffset` and it leads to stop the scrolling in `scrollViewDidScroll:` method.

Comment: I'm considering downvoting because this answer doesn't explain it's self you have just given code and that's it. Answer like that aren't very good. Good answer explain themselves, whilst experienced developers may understand this newer developers might not understand what's going on here. Not downvoted yet as giving the chance to improve.

Comment: This is sort of a hack, but it worked when all else failed.  So +1, but use only as a last resort.

Comment: I also use this delegate method, but I replace the body with a one-liner, e.g.: `scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);` to disable horizontal scrolling. I find it more readable, it's smaller, and there is no point doing the test for zero because there's virtually no overhead with code that runs this infrequently (i.e. a few tens of times per second max).

Comment: because you're changing the contentOffset after "didscroll", not like before 'willscroll', and this is a hammer solution, but i myself didn't downvote, because 18 upvotes and the answer is 75, so it's not worthy to downvote

Comment: @LolaRun But the solution is all about the resetting the changed content offset in "didScroll" method. In "willScroll", there won't be any change in content offset which we need to catch. Makes sense? I understand you didn't downvote, But to help you agree with the concept.

Comment: This approach interferes with UIScrollView's coasting and bouncing which completely changes the experience.  It doesn't cleanly do the job of only restricting scrolling in a certain direction.

Comment: @davew I don't get it. Do you want to prevent scrolling but bouncing? also above code doesn't interferes with other direction.

Comment: Even easier, use `scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0.0` to stop vertical scrolling and `scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0.0` to stop horizontal scrolling, in the `scrollViewDidScroll()` delegate function. However, I believe that making sure the `scrollView.contentSize` equals the `scrollView.frame.size` is a better (correct) solution. See @danbeaulieu answer.

Comment: @EranMarom Thank you for pointing out. Not sure, if you can set 'y' position alone by now. But, above code is written a long time before. We couldn't set 'x' or 'y' property in content offset directly. The other answer you pointed out is obviously correct one. But will not work if the actual content placement is more than the scrollview size and if you used autolayout to calculate the content size.

Comment: @DineshRaja Thanks, I did have problems using the contentSize solution in some cases (perhaps in cases the content size was reset later by the auto layouts mechanism). And yes, I mainly wanted to point out you can now set the x and y separately.

Comment: @i_am_jorf You are right, this is a hack. But all else does not fail. We could just set the contentSize appropriately instead of using a hack.

Answer (score 11):

since iOS7 use

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

//and create you page scroller with 3 pages

```
    self.pageView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.pageView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*3, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.pageView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.pageView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageView];
```

Comment: I don't think this will disable the scrolling behavior of a scrollview. Is it??

Comment: `self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;` helped me to resolve problem with smooth scrolling (not dragging). The problem was in method `scrollViewWillEndDragging:` - targetContentOffset was the same as scrollView.contentOffset and page detection logic doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 11):

> **Swift solution**

Create two outlets, one for your view and one for your scroll view:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

Then in your viewDidLayoutSubviews you can add the following code:

```
let scrollSize = CGSize(width: myView.frame.size.width, 
                        height: myView.frame.size.height)
scrollView.contentSize = scrollSize
```

What we've done is collected the height and width of the view and set the scrollViews content size to match it. This will stop your scrollview from scrolling horizontally.

---

**More Thoughts:**

CGSizeMake takes a width & height using CGFloats. You may need to use your UIScrollViews existing height for the second parameter. Which would look like this:

```
let scrollSize = CGSize(width: myView.frame.size.width, 
                        height: scrollView.contentSize.height)
```

Comment: What if you don't know the height or the width (universal device)? @danbeaulieu

Comment: @lukesIvi "myView.frame.width" is dynamically pulling the width from the "myView" IBOutlet.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, with **Swift** 4.2 you can use:

Disable vertical scroll:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0.0
}
```

Disable horizontal scroll:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0.0
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case the width of the contentView was greater than the width of UIScrollView and that was the reason for unwanted horizontal scrolling. I solved it by setting the width of contentView equal to width of UIScrollView.

Hope it helps someone

Comment: @Nostradamus happy to help

Comment: This should be the chosen answer.  Everything else is a distraction. Horizontal scrolling should not be happening when there is no horizontal content to scroll.

Answer (score 3):

You can select the view, then under `Attributes Inspector` uncheck `User Interaction Enabled` .

Answer (score 2):

Introduced in iOS 11 is a new property on `UIScrollView`

```
var contentLayoutGuide: UILayoutGuide
```

The documentation states that you:

> Use this layout guide when you want to create Auto Layout constraints related to the content area of a scroll view.

Along with any other Autolayout constraints that you might be adding you will want to constrain the `widthAnchor` of the `UIScrollView`'s `contentLayoutGuide` to be the same size as the "frame". You can use the `frameLayoutGuide` (also introduced in iOS 11) or any external width (such as your `superView`'s.)

example:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor)
])
```

Documentation: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2865870-contentlayoutguide

Answer (score 1):

@Gulfam Khan's answer is the correct one, I am adding imagery to help the concept get more visibility.

When we set the contentView to have equal width's with the Scroll view, if the multiplier is even slightly greater than 1:1, then we will get horizontal scrolling.

[image]

Here is what it produces:

[image]

If you do not want horizontal scrolling, you most likely do not have horizontal content that exceeds the width of the superview.

Therefore if you ensure the contentView width does not exceed the width of the scroll view, that will automatically resolve the problem as UIKit recognizes there is no horizontal content to scroll to. Like so:

[image]

Now you should only see vertical:

[image]

Comment: Worth checking your constraints. I'm not sure why the `multiplier` ends up as a decimal number, but this fixed it for me.

Comment: I think when you set the width to be equal when dragging , we think we set it to be exactly equal but we actually set it to be nearly exactly equal and then we get 1.00003 baked in as a multiplier.  It’s the imperfection of dragging getting baked in to your multiplier.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for some time trying unsuccessfully the various suggestions in this and other threads.

However, in another thread (not sure where) someone suggested that using a negative constraint on the UIScrollView worked for him.

So I tried various combinations of constraints with inconsistent results. What eventually worked for me was to add leading and trailing constraints of -32 to the scrollview and add an (invisible) textview with a width of 320 (and centered).

Answer (score 0):

I  had the tableview contentInset set in viewDidLoad (as below) that what causing the horizontal scrolling

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 30, 0, 0);
```

Check if there are any tableview contentInset set for different reasons and disable it

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
CGSize scrollSize = CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, scrollHeight);
[scrollView setContentSize: scrollSize];
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable horizontal scrolling by overriding `contentOffset` property in subclass.

```
override var contentOffset: CGPoint {
  get {
    return super.contentOffset
  }
  set {
    super.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: newValue.y)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Once I did it replacing the UIScrollView with a UITableView with only 1 cell, it worked fine.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

Use this single line.

`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;`