# Disabling vertical scrolling in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

There is an option in IB to uncheck vertical scrolling on a scrollview, but it doesnt seem to work.

How can the scrollview be set to only scroll horizontally, and not vertically in the code rather than IB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to disable vertical scrolling of scrollview iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062693/how-to-disable-vertical-scrolling-of-scrollview-iphone)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Try setting the contentSize's height to the scrollView's height. Then the vertical scroll should be disabled because there would be nothing to scroll vertically.

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width,scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: You just saved me a lot of time debugging this weird issue. Thanks!

Comment: @fabb how does one know when the frame is changed?

Comment: I think in auto-layout era this is outdated now.

Answer (score 138):

since iOS7:

first: the content size width must be equal to the width of your scrollview

second: in your initWithNibName:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

That´s it.

Comment: Wonderful solution. Worked like a charm. Will it affect the size of the rest of the views in my ViewController? (Buttons, Labels..) I mean, "self" is an UIViewController in my case

Comment: @voghDev no it has no effects to the subviews in your scrollview.

Comment: Amazing added this to the viewdidload method on my view controllers that were having issues.

Comment: if you're using navigationController and your scrollview is behind the navigationBar's title like mine use under viewDidLoad method. It solves.

Comment: You can achieve the same in the storyboard settings directly without any line of code. Just select the scroll view controller and uncheck the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" in the attribute inspector.

Comment: What about when your `UIScrollView` is inside a `UICollectionViewCell` for instance?

Comment: For me, sending the `collectionView` to front of all views solved the issue

Comment: Thank you!!! I was going crazy! This should be false by default!!!

Answer (score 49):

yes, pt2ph8's answer is right,

but if for some strange reason your contentSize should be higher than the UIScrollView, you can disable the vertical scrolling implementing the UIScrollView protocol method

```
 -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView;
```

just add this in your UIViewController

```
float oldY; // here or better in .h interface

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
    [aScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(aScrollView.contentOffset.x, oldY)];
    // or if you are sure you wanna it always on top:
    // [aScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(aScrollView.contentOffset.x, 0)];
}
```

it's just the method called when the user scroll your UIScrollView, and doing so you force the content of it to have always the same .y

Comment: God! Please DO NOT declare the oldY variable in .m file like `float oldY;` refer to the above code. That is a C-style variable symbol for per application, the variable MUST be declared as an instance member of controller class.

Answer (score 21):

Include the following method

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

and set the content size width of the scroll view equal to the width of the scroll view.

Comment: This can also be done in Storyboard by selecting the View Controller and unchecking the property there

Comment: I don't like this because it sets it for all scroll views... Wish you could be specific to one scroll view on the diagram w/o creating a new ScrollView class etc

Answer (score 20):

You need to pass 0 in content size to disable in which direction you want.

To disable vertical scrolling

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width,0);
```

To  disable horizontal scrolling

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0,scrollView.contentSize.height);
```

Comment: This will set the contentSize of the view to have 0 on the axis you set. ContentSize is referring to the size of the content, so we want to pass in the height of the screen to disable the vertical scrolling beyond that frame. the solution marked as correct, is correct.

Comment: This worked well for me. setting height as contentSize's height still got me vertical scrolling.

Comment: This did not work for me. Also tried self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets

Comment: This is it! Setting to the height of the Scroll View didn't work for me, but this did

Answer (score 18):

I updated the content size to disable vertical scrolling, and the ability to scroll still remained. Then I figured out that I needed to disable vertical bounce too, to disable completly the scroll.

Maybe there are people with this problem too.

Comment: You saved me. My contentSize and frame were the same and I could not for the life of me figure out what was wrong. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Your answer is why I love stackoverflow! :-) Holy smoke... this drove me nuts! You are right. It's the bounce effect. I want the bounce effect, but not when there is no need to scroll, so I'll be looking to disable/re-enable that effect now in code depending on whether there is a need to scroll.

Comment: Okay, very easy to enable/disable the bounces on a UIScrollView at runtime. In my case I only care about the height of the scroll content and this did the trick:       self.scrollView.bounces = (BOOL)(self.scrollView.contentSize.height > self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

Answer (score 12):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
    [aScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(aScrollView.contentOffset.x,0)];

}
```

you must have confirmed to  `UIScrollViewDelegate`

```
aScrollView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 5):

Just set the y to be always on top. 
Need to conform with UIScrollViewDelegate

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0.0
}
```

This will keep the Deceleration / Acceleration effect of the scrolling.

Answer (score 4):

On iOS 11 please remember to add the following, if you're interested in creating a scrollview that sticks to the screen bounds rather than a safe area.:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    [self.scrollView setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior:UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever];
}
```

Comment: after all. thank you thousand times sir! you saved my day

Answer (score 2):

A lot of answers include setting the `contentOffset` to 0. I had a case in which I wanted the view inside the scrollView to be centered. This did the job for me:

```
public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.contentOffset.y = -scrollView.contentInset.top
}
```

Comment: Works well in auto-layout.

Answer (score 1):

From *iOS11* one can use the following property

```
let frameLayoutGuide: UILayoutGuide
```

If you set constraints for *frameLayoutGuide.topAnchor* and *frameLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor* to the same anchors of some *subview* of your *scrollView* then vertical scroll will be disabled and the height of the *scrollView* will be equal to the height of its subview.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution is to forbid y-coordinate changes in your subclass.

```
override var contentOffset: CGPoint {
  get {
    return super.contentOffset
  }
  set {
    super.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: newValue.x, y: 0)
  }
}
```

This is the only suitable solution in situations when:

1. You are not allowed or just don't want to use delegate.
2. Your content height is larger than container height

Comment: This is the best answer! Should be selected as solution! Thank you mate you saved my day!

Comment: @imike my favorite solution is to use swizzling (: Check out the https://github.com/iwheelbuy/UIPanGestureRecognizerDirection repo

Answer (score 0):

I think you can

1. set directionalLockEnabled to true
2. set the contentView's width equals to superView's width.

That should work.