# Objective-C: How to disable verticall scrolling in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I am going to add a UIScrollView into a UIView programmatically.
I tried to use the following code for this but the scrollview is still not disabled.

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
...
  _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
  [self addSubview:_scrollView];
...
}
-(void)layoutSubviews {
...
  _scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 40);
  [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width * 2, 40)];
...
}
```

I think it should work but it's not working now.
Please advise me what the problem is.
Thanks

Comment: did you try setting scrolling to `NO` ?

Comment: well, I need horizontal scrolling though.

Answer (score 2):

Well, try to set the contentSize like this:

```
[_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width * 2, 0)];
```

Let me know the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `_scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;` 
This will disable `scrollView` to scroll vertically or horizontally.

**UPDATE: To avoid vertical scrolling only**

[Refer this link](http://http:/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844548/how-to-disable-vertical-scrolling-in-uiscrollview-obj-c)

You need to set frame of your `scrollView` and then set its `contentSize`

```
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width,scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: it disables both vertical and horizontal scrolling at the same time.
I need to enable only the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: in my question, both the height of scrollview frame and contentsize are currently 40. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

**For Objective - C**

```
CGFloat y = SCROLLVIEW_HEIGHT;

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, y);
```

**In Swift**

```
self.scrollView.contentSize.height = 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you must set - your scrollview content height is the scroll view height

```
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.contentSize.width,_scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Also the another way is

If the scrollView's contentSize.height is less than its bounds.size.height it won't scroll vertically.

You need to set

```
 scrollView.contentSize = (CGSize){<yourContentWidth>, 1.0}
```

Comment: in my question, both the height of scrollview frame and contentsize are currently 40. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need only Horizontal scrolling, vertical scrolling is not needed. Try the code below. I don't know where you stuck:

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self CreateScrollView];
}

(void)CreateScrollView 
{
   UIScrollView *Scroll_View = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 40)];
  [self addSubview:Scroll_View];
  [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width * 2, 40)];    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this:

[_scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

Comment: OP wants to disable scrolling . Your code will just hide the scrolling indicator. You should edit your answer. :)