# How do I make UICollectionView scroll both horizontally and vertically?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[image]

Hello..

I'm trying to create a calendar events catalog that will look something like this

I want it so that if I scroll vertically it changes the time showing in the catalog and if I scroll horizontally it will change the date of the calendar.

I made the vertical scrolling part work but I do not know how to also implement horizontal scrolling in swift..

Is there any way to make this work?

---

Im asking how to do this on swift.. Thank you

Comment: Base as TableView , In cell add CollecionView

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302772/uicollectionview-scroll-horizontal-and-vertical?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa