# How to lock the horizontal scrolling of a scrollView in iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

i have a scrollView. i want it to scroll only in one direction(VERTICAL). Is there a way in which i can lock the horizontal scrolling...?? ...

Comment: Please tell us more about why you want to do that, it helps us answer the question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Same (adapted) answer for you as in:**

[Disabling vertical scrolling in UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095713/disabling-vertical-scrolling-in-uiscrollview/5095989#5095989)

right, all answers here are ok...

but if for some strange reason your contentSize should be higher than the  `UIScrollView` in both dimensions, you can disable the horizontal scrolling implementing the `UIScrollView` protocol method `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView`

just add this in your `UIViewController`

```
float oldX; // here or better in .h interface

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
    [aScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(oldX, aScrollView.contentOffset.y)];
    // or if you are sure you wanna it always on left:
    // [aScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0, aScrollView.contentOffset.y)];
}
```

it's just the method called when the user scroll your `UIScrollView`, and doing so you force the content of it to have always the same .`x`

Comment: Hey I want to lock it in the Y direction (so the user is only able to scroll horizontally), when I change the `aScrollView.contentOffset.y` to `aScrollView.contentOffset.x` it just does not scroll in any direction anymore... (the one you've given does work as it should) Can you help me please?

Comment: @ummesekatze: try: [aScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(aScrollView.contentOffset.x, oldY)];

Comment: @meronix Thank you so much for this solution!  I've struggled with this issue for days until finally coming across your solution!  I added a bit more to your solution:

`- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    [scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(oldX, scrollView.contentOffset.y)];
    if (sender.contentOffset.x != 0) {
        CGPoint offset = sender.contentOffset;
        offset.x = 0;
        sender.contentOffset = offset;
    }`

Answer (score 13):

```
self.scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1, self.scrollview.frame.size.height * number_of_items);
```

should help.  I just locked my scroll view horizontally, by doing the similar technique.

Answer (score 10):

The safest and most successful method I've found to constrain the movement of a scroll view is to subclass **UIScrollView** and override **setContentOffset:animated:** and **setContentOffset:** methods (code below).

The advantage of overriding these methods is that it directly alters the requested **contentOffset** before any of the UIKit code starts to act on it, avoiding any of the side effects that can occur when modifying the contentOffset in **scrollViewDidScroll:** or other **UIScrollViewDelegate** methods.

It takes just a few minutes to create the new subclass, and it works like a charm.

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // restrict movement to vertical only
    CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(0, contentOffset.y);
    [super setContentOffset:newOffset animated:animated];
}

- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    // restrict movement to vertical only
    CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(0, contentOffset.y);
    [super setContentOffset:newOffset];    
}
```

Comment: I like this solution because you can also use it in Interface Builder by setting the Custom Class from UIScrollView to the subclass. +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062693/how-to-disable-vertical-scrolling-of-scrollview-iphone) question, you have to set the scrollable size to the corresponding size of the view so that there is nothing to scroll.

Answer (score 2):

If the UIScrollView's `contentSize` property has the same as the actual width of the UIScrollView, then no horizontal scrolling will be possible.

Are you wanting to stop horizontal scrolling when horizontal scrolling would be valid? (i.e. the `contentSize` is wider than the actual UIScrollView width?) If 'yes', why are you wanting to do that?

Comment: @ occulus:yes occulus..... i want to stop it even when the content size is greater than the actual scrollView width

Comment: Ok, have updated my answer and asked "Why are you wanting to do that?". Let me know because it affects the strategy.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
self.ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.ScrollView.frame.size.width, 1450);
```

here 1450 is my view height.

Comment: You mark the text that is supposed to be code, then you click the code hightlighter button. Or you indent with four spaces. That makes the text get code formatted.

Answer (score 1):

The scrollView is only scrollable horizontally if you set the contentSize width bigger than the scrollView frame. If you set the contentSize width to the same as the scrollview it won't scroll. For example

`UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)]
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 300)]`

Answer (score 1):

oh since iOS7 use this (in initWithNibName):

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

and create the page scroller with 3 pages

```
self.pageView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.pageView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*3, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.pageView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[self.pageView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the contentSize was higher than the UIScrollView for x and y. For me meronixe's answer worked out quite well, but was for my needs not quite complete. Unfortunately the horizontal scrollbar was still visible.

This I could change with the following code in

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView

[self.webView.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

Make `contentOffset.x = 0` for disable horizontal scroll

```
   extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
          func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0//to lock horizontal scrolling
            //scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0//to lock vertical scrolling
        }
    }
```

**Additionally you can disable scroll indicator as**

```
  scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false//to disable HorizontalScrollIndicator
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false//to disable VerticalScrollIndicator
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution :
You can set the align top position to -200 or whatever value you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Horizontal or Vertical Scroll Lock**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x != 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
    }
}
```

You can change the x to y for vertical scrolling.

Make sure to add `UIScrollViewDelegate` like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

}
```

And set the delegate for the ScrollView

```
scrollView.delegate = self
```

Comment: Did you copy any text/code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51574229)?

Comment: Yes, it was the best answer to this also and not covered here. Is there a better way to link an answer from another question?

Comment: vote to close this question as duplicate of the one that the linked post answers.

Comment: There is a lot of useful info here not captured in the other question.