# How To Disable The HorizontalScrollBar in Webview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

How To Disable The HorizontalScrollBar in Webview , when the move the webview i need to disable the scroll in horizontal scroll in webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls check this.
[How to lock the horizontal scrolling of a scrollView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271521/how-to-lock-the-horizontal-scrolling-of-a-scrollview-in-ios)