# Scrolling locked in iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I have a weird issue on my mobile website when viewed in Safari on an iPhone (5, 6). When i open the left slide menu and then open a submenu (i.e. Electrical Solutions) that has considerably many items that cannot fit vertically on the screen, the scroll down touch gets locked and can't view the remaining elements in the submenu. However, if i open another Submenu (i.e. Industries) with the previous Submenu kept open, the scroll down unlock and works normally and now i can view the other elements in the first submenu.
What i tried: I checked the `overflow` in all these elements and nothing looks wrong and also added the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` touch to the body but still no luck.
What are my other options to check?

Comment: Check out [this][1] answer, maybe you'll find something usefull here.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271521/how-to-lock-the-horizontal-scrolling-of-a-scrollview-in-ios

Comment: @JosipIvic That is xcode, the question is about a mobile website

Comment: Please post code so that people can view the issue and replicate it

Comment: Also I would award your bounty before it disappears. Just letting you know

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Rohan, the issue is resolved om the IOS I tried on. And you can see the code on the website mentioned. But still some some iOS have the issue even after it's been resolved.

Comment: I apologize if you did actually indeed post the code on the website my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see you use 
`-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` at the `.sidebar-menu` but not at the `.submenu`, though this should not be an issue, but you might try to add it to the submenu as well. 
Something else is that your `.sidebar-menu` has no `overflow:hidden`, which I do recommend and might be the cause of your issue.

IOS is really nasty with scrolling in my experience and it is very hard to track if you have many layered elements. Also read https://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios it might give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you very much. But if you could later shed some light on the fact why with 2 submenus there is no bug and otherwise.

Comment: Yes that is a very good point, I honestly have no clue. It does not seem consistend behaviour.