# How to disable horizontal scrolling in UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll

I have a `scrollView` of 280(w) x 350(h) and a `content view` of 840(w) x 405(h).

I switch between the views with a `segmented control` like this:

```
- (IBAction)segmentedClicked:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    CGFloat x = sender.selectedSegmentIndex * self.personalDetailsScrollView.frame.size.width;
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(x, 0);
    [self.personalDetailsScrollView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];
}
```

I want to disable the regular horizontal scrolling so only the segmented buttons will scroll the view horizontally. The vertical scroll should stay active.

Tried to use  *-(void)scrollViewDidScroll* and the solution offered here: ([How to lock the horizontal scrolling of a scrollView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271521/how-to-lock-the-horizontal-scrolling-of-a-scrollview-in-ios)) but it didn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: Try to change the scroll view content size as per width size

Comment: Maybe this might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062693/how-to-disable-horizontal-scrolling-of-scrollview-iphone

Comment: Just set its `contentSizeWidth` 0 ..... !!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but this is the approach I'd take:

In `UIScrollView`, there is a property:

`@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer`

So I'd make my own new `UIPanGestureRecognizer` extension and override:

```
- (CGPoint)translationInView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGPoint tmp = [super translationInView:view];
    return CGPointMake(0, tmp.y);
}
```

Add that gesture recognizer to the `scrollview`, then call:

```
[scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:youCustomOne];
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (IBAction)segmentedClicked:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
       CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
       CGPoint point = CGPointMake(self.personalDetailsScrollView.frame.size.width, 0);
     }
    [self.personalDetailsScrollView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but I see there is still no accepted answer, so I'll give it a go.

It sounds like what you are trying to do is use 1 controller to effectively hold 3 separate screens.  You're trying to switch between the screens depending on what the user selects in a `UISegmentedControl`, and you don't want the user to be able to pan between the views by just horizontally swiping.  Why not just have 3 different view controllers?  I think that is the more expected way to setup what you are trying to do, and therefore you will find it much easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3, Set `UIScrollViewDelegate` to your class and then use below code.

```
scrollView.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.x>0 {
            webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0.0
        }
    }
```