# UIScroll View Not Working As Expected

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, ios9

I have a scene where I just want the scroll to be vertical not horizontal. I have tried to program it to disable but that doesn't seem to work. I also run into the issue where it isn't auto resizing to different phone screens. Im kinda new at this and I'm just really stuck. Any help?

Disable Code:

```
@IBOutlet var scrollview: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollview.contentSize.height = 800
    scrollview.contentSize.width = 0
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062693/how-to-disable-horizontal-scrolling-of-uiscrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not applying constraints on UIScrollView properly now first of all you have to properly add constraint on scrollview and no need to set contentsize from code.

> http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

Hope this tutorial will help you better understand the ScrollView

Answer (score 3):

I think problem is with this line

```
scrollview.contentSize.width=0
```

Try to set width equal to screen width like this,

```
scrollview.contentSize.width=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
```

Scrollview will scroll horizontally when it's contentSize.width is greater than viewcontroller's width.

Hope it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 1000)
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
}
```